# Limit vmware virtual pc to certain computers

Tags: virtual-machine, permissions, vmware

I need a virtual pc, that is only usable in our workplace. So If someone copy this virtual hard drive and take it home, they can't get the files from it.

How Can I achieve this?
Is it possible to make a virtual pc (windows 7) only work if the host computer is allowed to use it? Or Can I use a second authentication system using vmware?

Answer (score 0):

If you think about this in the same way as a physical disk:

'What if someone stole my Hard Drive?'

The only way you could stop them from using it (Or stealing data from it), is to encrypt it.

Personally, I have never encrypted a VHD, but I found some documentation if this is the route you would like to take ...

http://www.virtualizationpractice.com/virtual-disk-encryption-3760/
http://www.vmware.com/pdf/ace_encrypt_bg.pdf

Also, it is quite concerning that your users have acces to the VHD if you want to have it secure ... You may want to think of a way to provide it for users, without them acually needing access to the VHD itself

Comment: Only way I could use encryption as a copy protection if every time a user wants to start the virtual machine would need a different password, generated by a local server.